# To understand a notation on Riemann integral

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, proof-explanation, riemann-integration

I was reading proof of Riemann condition theorem on $\mathbb{R^n}$ that in the proof, I couldn't understand this:

> ''Choose a partition $P$ so that $L(f,P)$ is within $\epsilon/2$ of the integral $\int_Q f$ and a partition $P'$ so that $U(f,P')$ is within $\epsilon/2$ of the  integral $\int_Q f.$''

**My question is:** Can you say that what is ''$L(f,P)$ is within $\epsilon/2$ of the integral $\int_Q f$'' mean as mathematically? Can you explain? I couldn't understand this sentence, especially ''within''. Thanks...

Comment: I am assuming it simply means $ |L(f,P) - \int_Q f | < \epsilon /2 $

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that $\int_Qf-L(f,P)<\frac\varepsilon2$.